# Конвертация xlsm и xls в командной строке

Tags: windows, excel, xls

Как конвертировать файлы между форматами xls и xlsm в командной строке? Есть ли такой способ?

Для конвертации xls в xlsm подходит OMPM от Microsoft, но, насколько я знаю, он работает только в одном направлении.

Comment: А какой инструментарий Вы хотите использовать? Если средства Microsoft Office Excel, то есть 2 часто используемых способа: через вызов vb-скрипта, который запустить Excel и стартует макрос конвертации. И запуск нужного Excel-документа, в котором макрос прописан в автозагрузке. Как понимаете, нужно ещё и иметь макрос (впрочем, там простой код по пересохранению документа в нужный формат).

Comment: Впрочем, там простой код в макросе по пересохранению документа в нужный формат.  **:-)**  Основные две функции: `Workbooks.Open` и `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`

Comment: @Daemon-5, видимо, придется обратить внимание на vb, никогда с ним не сталкивался. В иделе это было бы какое-нибудь стороннее ПО или какая-нибудь библиотека для питона. В частности, конвертация нужна для работы с файлами через openpyxl, который не умеет с xls.

Comment: Надумаете использовать VBA, скину скрипт, который я использовал давно ещё для конвертации всех xls,xlsm в xlsx в заданном каталоге. Стартовал его вручную из Excel.

Comment: @Daemon-5, был бы признателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю свой вариант, удовлетворяющий требованиям запуска из командной строки. VB скрипт запускается под WSH.

### Вызов:

`cscript converter.vbs <Папка-источник файлов, требующих преобразование> <Папка-содержит преобразованные файлы>`

xls -> xlsm либо наоборот xlsm -> xls

Пример вызова: `cscript converter.vbs D:\Tst_Fldr\From\ D:\Tst_Fldr\To\`

Результат работы:

[image: Результат работы]
a.xls - обычный текстовый файл с расширением `xls`

### Суть действий:

1. считываются файлы в ***Папке-источнике***;
2. в цикле каждый файл ***Папки-источника*** открывается как рабочая книга MS Excel (oExcl.Workbooks.Open(oFl.Path));
3. проверяется формат файла (oExclWB.FileFormat) и в зависимости от значения:

   ***52*** (xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (*.xlsm))

   либо

   ***56*** - (Excel8 (*.xls)) производится действие аналогичное MS Excel ("Сохранить как") с требуемыми параметрами (oExclWB.SaveAs ...)
4. все, что не попадает под формат файла, то не обрабатывается;
5. пишется минимальная информация о действиях.

   ```
   'конвертирует файлы вида xls в xlsm и обратно
   'если на входе xls то результат xlsm
   'и наоборот xlsm -> xls
   'параметр 1: папка - содержить файлы которые требуется сконвертировать;
   'параметр 2: папка - для сохранения результата;
   'получаем и обрабатываем переданные параметры
   Set oArgs = WScript.Arguments 

   Select Case oArgs.Count
       Case 2
           sFldrFrm = oArgs(0)
           sFldrTo = oArgs(1)
       Case Else
           'Завершаем работы
           Wscript.Echo("Количество переданных параметров не равно двум")
           WScript.Quit
   End Select 

   Wscript.Echo ("Начало преобразования файлов:")

   Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set oFldr = oFSO.GetFolder(sFldrFrm)

   Set oExcl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   '
   'скрыли MS Excel
   oExcl.Visible = False   'True 

   'отключили окна запросов для случая перезаписи файлов
   oExcl.displayalerts=false

   For Each oFl in oFldr.Files
       Set oExclWB = oExcl.Workbooks.Open(oFl.Path)
       'определяем формат книги MS Excel на основе FileFormat
       '52 - xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (*.xlsm)
       '56 - Excel8 (*.xls)
       'Wscript.Echo (oExclWB.FileFormat)
       Select Case  oExclWB.FileFormat
           'и в зависимости от этого проводим конвертацию
           'WScript.Echo (sFldrTo & oFl.Name)

           Case 52
               oExclWB.SaveAs left(sFldrTo & oFl.Name, len(sFldrTo & oFl.Name)-1), 56
               Wscript.Echo ("Файл: " & oFl.Path & " преобразован в: " & left(sFldrTo & oFl.Name, len(sFldrTo & oFl.Name)-1))
               'Wscript.Echo (left(sFldrTo & oFl.Name, len(sFldrTo & oFl.Name)-1))
           Case 56
               oExclWB.SaveAs sFldrTo & oFl.Name & "m", 52         
               Wscript.Echo ("Файл: " & oFl.Path  & " преобразован в: " & sFldrTo & oFl.Name & "m")
           Case Else
               Wscript.Echo ("Файл: " & oFl.Path  & " не преобразован, не соответствует требованиям форматов ")
       End Select
       oExclWB.Close
       'формат вызова *.SaveAs( FileName , FileFormat , Password , WriteResPassword , ReadOnlyRecommended , CreateBackup , AccessMode , ConflictResolution , AddToMru , TextCodepage , TextVisualLayout , Local )
   Next
   oExcl.Quit
   Wscript.Echo ("Преобразование файлов завершено")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Преобразование файлов из *Excel***

Две процедуры - выбор файла, создание нового файла. Код разместить в любом файле *Excel* с поддержкой макросов. Запуск преобразования можно назначить на открытие книги, любому объекту или запускать в "ручном" режиме макрос *ChoiceOfFile*.

В директории с файлом-обработчиком создается папка *Conversion*, куда складываются преобразованные файлы.

"Направление" преобразования определяется в коде:

- исходный файл с расширением *.xls* или *.xlsx* - создание файла *.xlsm* (*.xlsb*)
- исходный файл с поддержкой макросов - создание файла *.xls* (*.xlsx*)

*Выбор файла*

```
Sub ChoiceOfFile()
Dim FDial As FileDialog
Dim sFName As String
Dim sShortFName As String
    Set FDial = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FDial
        .Filters.Clear: .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*"
        .Filters.Add "Allfiles", "*.*"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
        .Title = "Choose the file": .ButtonName = "Open"

        If .Show = False Then
            MsgBox "File didn’t chosen!", 48, "ERROR": Exit Sub
        Else
            sFName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    Set FDial = Nothing
    Call FileConversion(sFName) ' к преобразованию'
End Sub
```

*Преобразование файла*

```
Sub FileConversion(sFName As String)
Dim wBook As Workbook
Dim sFldr As String, sNewName As String, sFormat As String
    sFldr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Conversion" & "\" ' путь к папке для сохранения'
    If Dir(sFldr, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir sFldr ' если нет, создаем папку'
    sNewName = Mid$(sFName, InStrRev(sFName, "\") + 1) ' имя без пути'
    sNewName = Left$(sNewName, InStrRev(sNewName, ".") - 1) ' имя без расширения'

    ' имя новой книги с расширением и формат сохранения'
    If Right(sFName, 1) = "s" Or Right(sFName, 1) = "x" Then ' исходный без макросов'
        sNewName = sNewName & ".xlsm": sFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        'sNewName = sNewName & ".xlsb": sFormat = xlExcel12'
    Else  ' исходный с макросами'
        sNewName = sNewName & ".xls":  sFormat = xlExcel8
        'sNewName = sNewName & ".xlsx": sFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook'
    End If

    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFName) ' открываем книгу'

    With wBook ' новую книгу сохраняем и закрываем'
        .SaveAs Filename:=sFldr & sNewName, FileFormat:=sFormat, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With

    Set wBook = Nothing
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub
```

Осталось написать скрипт, открывающий книгу )

Можно *передать путь к файлу без окна выбора* (естественно, если этот путь известен):

```
Sub jjj()
    Call FileConversion(sFName)
End Sub
```

Или, как вариант, присвоить этот путь переменной в процедуре и запускать непосредственно *FileConversion* (в этом случае передаваемого параметра нет и в скобках после названия писать ничего не нужно):

```
Dim FName As String
    FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\папка1\папка25\книга12.xlsx"
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как теперь автоматизировать процесс, чтобы можно было передать расположение файла в качестве параметра, а не выбирать его вручную?

Comment: Добоваил в ответ

Comment: Прошу прощения за назойливость, но я пока не очень понимаю, как это можно было бы сделать из командной строки или питона. Можете отослать к гайдам, если такие есть.

Comment: Увы, ту я бессилен ). Запуск обработки можно прописат при открытии книги: Private Sub WorkBook_Open(): Call FileConversion(sFName) : End Sub

Answer (score 1):

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"

Function procSaveAS(fn As String) As Boolean

'
' procSaveAS Макрос
'
'
   On Error GoTo ErrSt


'   If fn = "" Then GoTo ErrSt
'   End If
'
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Workbooks.Open Filename:=fn, _
       AddToMru:=False, Notify:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   st = LCase(Right(fn, 4))
   fnn = fn
   If st = "xlsm" Then
    fnn = Left(fnn, Len(fnn) - 1)

   End If
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fnn & "x", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   ActiveWindow.Close
    procSaveAS = True
    Exit Function
ErrSt:
    procSaveAS = False
End Function

Sub ConvertFormat()

'

    Const myProgramPath As String = """c:\windows\system32\CMD.exe"""
    Const lstfile As String = "C:\temp\123.txt" 'временный файл со списком всех файлов к обработке
    Const FP As String = "C:\WORK\" 'каталог в котором нужно конвертировать файлы

exec = myProgramPath & " /c dir /b /s " & FP & "*.xls|findstr /i/v .xls.>" & lstfile & "&dir /b /s " & FP & "*.xlsm>>" & lstfile
Shell exec
Shell """c:\windows\system32\CMD.exe""" & " /c ping.exe localhost -n 4"


Dim objStream, str
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Charset = "cp866"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile lstfile
arr = Split(objStream.ReadText, vbNewLine)
objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing

Dim i As String
For Each st In arr
    If st <> "" Then
     i = st
     If procSaveAS(i) Then
      Kill i
     End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Нужно вызывать процедуру ConvertFormat.В константах описаны пути каталога для обработки (и временного файла).
Идет поиск всех файлов расширения *.xls и *.xlsm.
Список файлов заносится во временный текстовый файл.
Каждый файл и списка обрабатывается процедурой procSaveAS.
После чего удаляется.

Comment: Поскольку тогда ещё было лень реализовывать рекурсивный поиск файлов средствами VBA, рекурсивный поиск был реализован командой **dir**. Если после обработки файлы удалять не надо, закоментарить команду **Kill i**

Comment: Бывало, что команда **Shell exec** исполнялась долго и временный файл не успевал создаться. Приходилось ещё раз запускать скрипт, а переделывать уже было лень...